# Duplicate questions, where to find them

Tags: discussion, duplicate

When I view a question and immediately below the question instead of an answer is the block which states this is a 'duplicate question'.  That's all well and fine but how do I find the original question so I can see the answers?

Comment: There is a search box on the top right of the page.  Google searches will often lead you to this site as well.  Finally when you start building your question you will see suggested related questions either above the question form or to the right of it.

Comment: If you are talking about a question which _has already been closed as duplicate_, there will be a link at the top of the page to the preferred question as well as the block comment that it is closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson meta access require 5 reputation point.

Answer (score 4):

Below the question title. Two styles of banners are used (the old one is actually inserted as editable text in the question, the new one is not part of the question text):

- new

  [image]
- old

  [image]